# what is the difference between “make of” and “make from”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

I want to ask a thing make from/of something but I don't know how.

What are they make from?
What are they make of?
what do they make from?
what do they make of?

Comment: I think you need "What are they made from?"

Comment: For *made of* vs. *made from*, see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65892/made-of-vs-made-from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be *make from/of*, it should be *made from/of*. *Made* is the past form of *make*, and since the item you are asking about already exists, you want to ask what it's *made from*.
For this context, there is little or no difference between *made from* and *made of* (which is a shortened form of *made out of*).

Example:

> Person 1: "What are car tires made out of?"
>   Person 2: "They are made of rubber."